# nginx subdomain and DNS too many redirects

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server

I just installed nginx and set it to work over an apache installation. As a matter of fact, my rules are:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Readl-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://example.com:8080;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

and I wanted to configure a subdomain by:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com:8080/sub;
    }

    location ~/\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

And configuring my DNS like so:

```
    NAME     |     TYPE     |     TARGET
    //empty         A           45.23.67.89
     sub           CNAME        example.com
```

I waited for propagation, but i'm getting "too many redirects" in chrome...

The response is always 301, and redirected to the IP:80, I'm guessing that this is caused because of the A line in DNS... howver domain.com does redirect to apache and I do get the "it works" we all know so well...

Can anyone one point me to the right direction please?

Thanks!